# How do I convert a list into readable format with commas and &'s?

Tags: python, pokeapi

I am using pypokedex API for my project. I have a list that contains the different abilities of a particular pokemon. Some pokemon has 1 ability while others have more. I want these abilities to be In proper readable English which I can give as an output. For eg. Psyduck has 3 abilities according to the API data received. The three abilities are damp, cloud-nine and swift-swim. These are printed as`[Ability(name='damp', is_hidden=False), Ability(name='cloud-nine', is_hidden=False), Ability(name='swift-swim', is_hidden=True)]` I want to only take the name of the ability and format it as a normal person would do. Expected Result: Psyduck has 3 abilities viz. damp, cloud nine and swift swim. The same I need for the type as each pokemon can have 1 or 2 types. If you have a way to get my expected result please answer the question. The rest of the code for reference :

```
import pypokedex

def pokedex_func():
try:
    inp_poke_name = input(
        "Please input the Pokémon's name you want to find information about : "
    )
    p = pypokedex.get(name=inp_poke_name)
    poke_name = p.name[0].upper() + p.name[1:]

    # Pokemon Name and Dex
    print("The Pokémon you searched was " + poke_name)
    print("The Pokédex number of " + poke_name + " is " + str(p.dex))

    # Height and Weight
    print(poke_name + " weighs " + str(p.weight / 10) +
          " Kg and has a height of " + str(p.height * 10) + "cm")

    # TODO : Add a way to tell the user the type of pokemon they searched for.
    print(p.types)

    # All the different base_stats
    print(poke_name + " has " + str(p.base_stats.hp) + " health points, " +
          str(p.base_stats.attack) + " attack points, " +
          str(p.base_stats.defense) + " defense points and " +
          str(p.base_stats.speed) + " speed points")

    # TODO : Add a way to tell the user the abilities of pokemon they searched for.
    print(p.abilities)

    # Pokemon Image/Sprite
    print(p.sprites.front['default'])
except:
    print("Pokémon not found")


pokedex_func()
```

Output for Psyduck :

```
Please input the Pokémon's name you want to find information about : Psyduck
The Pokémon you searched was Psyduck
The Pokédex number of Psyduck is 54
Psyduck weighs 19.6 Kg and has a height of 80cm
['water']
Psyduck has 50 health points, 52 attack points, 48 defense points and 55 speed points
[Ability(name='damp', is_hidden=False), Ability(name='cloud-nine', is_hidden=False), 
Ability(name='swift-swim', is_hidden=True)]
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/54.png
```

Note: This is later going to be a discord bot using Discord.Py. Hence there is a link to an image that I can send directly to any channel and discord will embed the image. Also, all these outputs will be a discord message.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `p.abilities` is an array of objects you can loop through them:

```
output = ""

for index, ability in enumerate(p.abilities):
    output += ability.name
    
    if index == len(p.abilities)-2:
        output += " and "
    elif index == len(p.abilities)-1:
        pass
    else:
        output += ", "
    
print(output)
```

It's not the most pythonic, but it's simple and understandable.

Comment: I found a issue with this the output I get is this : damp and cloud-nineswift-swim, This is the unexpected output. Expected Output : Damp, cloud-nine and swift-swim. The hypen - I can remove by finding it using the contains and replacing it